# How to add unique message id to soap 1.2 request if it is not present?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf

our webservice is used by a system that is not sending the message id correctly. (not in the soap request at all!) I am looking for ways on how to add a message id if this is not
present in the actual call. If it is not present the entire call fails on the fact that a required property is not present.

Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

Comment: You want something for client side or for server side? If you want it on server side, why not just set a id before validation?

Comment: On the server side, I need to add it when a client calls our webservice. How can can i do this before validation?

Comment: How is the validation done? Are we speaking about schema validation so is some attribute marked as mandatory is not present SOAP default is sent back to the client?

Comment: I am not sure how the validation is done, my server is complaining that a required field is missing. The Message Id, so i would like to fill in this Message ID when it is not present.

Comment: The error message is: org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: A required header representing a Message Addressing Property is not present

Comment: It will be useful if you provide an example of request server is expecting and what client is sending. Acording to your last comment, it looks like what it is messing is the header and not just a simple property. If WS-Addressing is not need at all, you can remove its necessity from the server side but maybe someone in the middle is using it. See this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Addressing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution [here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cxf-users/201202.mbox/%3C4F44C735.3040109@gmail.com%3E), but that doesn't seem to work.

Came up with this solution which works for me: create an interceptor which checks for the MessageID header and adds it to the message if it doesn't exist:

```
package my.package;

import org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapHeader;
import org.apache.cxf.headers.Header;
import org.apache.cxf.message.Message;
import org.apache.cxf.phase.AbstractPhaseInterceptor;
import org.apache.cxf.phase.Phase;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

public class HeaderInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {

    private static final String SOAP_HEADER_KEY = "org.apache.cxf.headers.Header.list";
    private static final String NAMESPACE_URI   = "http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing";
    private static final String QUALIFIED_NAME  = "wsa:MessageID";
    private static final String LOCAL_NAME      = "MessageID";

    public HeaderInterceptor() {
        // phases: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html
        // 'pre protocol' seems to be the best moment to check the header, if we do it earlier the headers don't exist in the message object so we can't re-use the 'owner document'
        // if we do it later the unmarshalMAPs method (in MAPCodec.java) will already have processed the headers and will not process our added header
        super(Phase.PRE_PROTOCOL);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
        ArrayList<SoapHeader> headers = (ArrayList<SoapHeader>) message.get(SOAP_HEADER_KEY);

        // if the header doesn't exist and we have at least one header to access 'owner document' we can create and add our own MessageID header
        if(!messageIdHeaderExists(headers) && headers.size() > 0) {
            Element existingHeaderElement = (Element) headers.get(0).getObject();

            // use the existing header element to create our own MessageID header with random UUID
            Element element = existingHeaderElement.getOwnerDocument().createElementNS(NAMESPACE_URI, QUALIFIED_NAME);
            element.appendChild(existingHeaderElement.getOwnerDocument().createTextNode("uuid:" + UUID.randomUUID().toString()));

            QName qname = new QName(NAMESPACE_URI, LOCAL_NAME);
            SoapHeader header = new SoapHeader(qname, element);

            // by default a SoapHeader is created with 'direction out'
            header.setDirection(Header.Direction.DIRECTION_IN);

            headers.add(header);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Checks if the MessageID header exists in the list of headers.
     *
     * @param headers list of headers
     * @return true if the MessageID header exists, false if not
     */
    private Boolean messageIdHeaderExists(ArrayList<SoapHeader> headers) {
        for(SoapHeader header:headers) {
            if(header.getName().getLocalPart().equalsIgnoreCase(LOCAL_NAME)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }        

}
```

Define the interceptor in your Spring context:

```
<bean id="headerInterceptor" class="my.package.HeaderInterceptor" />

<jaxws:endpoint implementor="#service" address="/ws">
    <jaxws:inInterceptors>
        <ref bean="headerInterceptor" />
    </jaxws:inInterceptors>
</jaxws:endpoint>
```

Tested with CXF version 2.6.1.
More info on interceptors: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html